# How can I express variables with array in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am a beginner learning ReactJs.
I am trying to express data from firebase.

when I put {quizes[0].quiz}  this was working.
But, if I want to use 'qno' variable, what should I do?

```
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import {dbService} from 'fbase';

const QuizPlay = () => {
    const {cateId} = useParams();
    const [qno, setQno] = useState(0);
    const [quizes, setQuizes] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
            dbService
            .collection("quizes")
            .where('cateId','==',cateId)
            .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                const quizArray = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data(),
                }));
                setQuizes(quizArray);
            })
        }, [cateId]);

return (
        <div className="container">
            {quizes[qno].quiz} <=== error
        </div>
 )

}

export default QuizPlay;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `quizes` has been populated `quizes[qno]` - (`quizes[0]`) - is `undefined` and therefore does not have a `quiz` property.

Try

```js
<div className="container">
    {quizes[qno]?.quiz}
</div>
```

assuming your compiler supports optional chaining, or if not:

```js
<div className="container">
    {quizes.length > 0 && quizes[qno].quiz}
</div>
```

Comment: Wow {quizes[qno]?.quiz} is working!!!!

Comment: Thank you so much.  {quizes[qno]?.quiz} <---- how does it work? What ? mean? I appreciate it anyway.

Comment: Optional chaining as documented here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happening because when the component is mounted the first time the quizzes haven't been loaded yet. So quizes is empty. Try this:

```
{quizes && quizes[qno].quiz}
```

Or

```
{quizes.length > 0 && quizes[qno].quiz}
```

Could you tell us exactly what error your getting?

Comment: It says too many re-renders. I think I should not combine useState constant.